# Vue JS with regular bootstrap

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

I´ve been searching around for a while now, but can´t seem to find the correct answer.
I´m going to start a new Vue JS project which will use bootstrap. The bootstrap-vue project seems to be the obvious choice. The problem is that the company I am working for has created their own implementation of Boostrap (v4) with their own styles and elements. 
I can understand that the use of regular bootstrap which uses jQuery does not play nicely with Vue and it´s shadow dom.
But what is exactly the problem? I am not using jQuery any other place in the code, and bootstrap is not managing the datamodel. So why is the use of Vue js and regular bootstrap together unrecommended?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

People doesn't approve jQuery + Vue for the simple reason that jQuery is not necessary and duplicates a lot of Vue functionality being less reactive, but **jQuery CAN coexist with Vue**.

If you start a new project I would recommend using another alternative (Bulma, Bootstrap vue, etc) that is more agnostic and does not depend on any other library.

In your case, I understand that only CSS classes have been customized. I think you could install the latest version of Bootstrap-vue and add those customizations, if the bootstrap version is the same, it should not collide too much. Still, I understand that it will be complicated, since Bootstrap-vue generates the HTML from its already created components, which makes it a bit complicated that the first one looks the way you want without adjusting.